# How to convert NSMutableData to NSString on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, string, typeconverter

I received an NSMutableData from a server and now I want to convert it to an NSString. Any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the `initWithData:` initializer:

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Change the encoding to that of the source data.

Comment: If he's getting data from a server he very likely wants NSUTF8StringEncoding instead.