# how convert NSMutableData to NSString?

Tags: iphone

how convert NSMutableData to NSString?

```
NSString *strData = @"Bonjour tout le monde, je voudrais vous présenter la Société Futur";
NSLog(@"before encryption : %@",strData);
NSMutableData *objNSData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];

objNSData = [objNSData EncryptAES:@"samplekey"];
   ///NSLog(@"encryption : %@", objNSData);
   NSString * strData1= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objNSData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"encryption : %@", strData1);
```

Comment: See my Latest answer....

Comment: thx bro but i need work with AES256 not 64

Answer (score 2):

Try with below

```
NSString * strData1= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myMutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: can i convert NSString to NSMutableData

Comment: when i use  NSString * strData1= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myMutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    i have  encryption : (null)

Comment: NSString * strData1= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:objNSData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 
    NSLog(@"encryption : %@", strData1);  i have encryption : (null)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593362/how-to-convert-nsmutabledata-to-nsstring-on-iphone)

For different encoding , there is other methods also..

**Converting NSString to NSData**

```
NSString* str= @"teststring";
NSData* data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**Update**

For Encryption and decryption, See This [Link](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/) and download source code...

Comment: i use this code but when i want saved the encrypt data and i want decrypted i have many exception  .can i convert NSString to NSMutabedata?

Comment: the result for vonversion is nullNSString *key = @"my password";
 NSString *secret = @"text to encrypt";
 
 NSData *plain = [secret dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSData *cipher = [plain AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
 //NSString * strData1= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cipher encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSString * strData1= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cipher encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 0):

Following links may help you -

1. http://linglong117.blog.163.com/blog/static/27714547201011142423968/
2. [AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)
3. https://gist.github.com/838614

These can help you to go through with the encryption methods and their correct implementation using category.